# how to solve two sum problem with python in O(n) time complexity with an array that include negative integers

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures

I am currently learning **dynamic programming** and i amlooking for a solution to the 2 sum python problem in O(n) time complexity. Please note that the array include negative integers

**arr = [2,-1,4,7,11]**

## using the two pointers method

```
target = 10 # sum of (-1,11)

def two_sum(arr, target):
  arr.sort()
  left = 0
  right = len(arr)-1
  while left < right:
    current_sum = arr[left] + arr[right]
    if current_sum == target:
       return [arr[left], arr[right]]
    elif current_sum < target:
      left += 1
    elif current_sum > target:
      right -= 1
  return []

# time complexity 0(n log(n))
# space complexity 0(log 1)
```

Unfortunately, the solution I have above is in `0(n log(n))` time complexity.

what would be the **dynamic programming** approach to achieve the above in `0(n)` time complexity?

my current **dynamic programming** approach solution only work when the array is made of only non negative integers.

## example

## dynamic programming

```
arr = [1,2,4,6] # non negative integers
target = 3

def two_sum(arr, target):
  seen = {}
  for idx, value in enumerate(arr):
    remaining = target - value
    if remaining in seen:
      return [seen[remaining], value]
    seen[idx] = value
  return []
```

Comment: What do you expect as the solution? As you have a return in the while loop, you will be able to have only one answer and not all solutions. in the arr you gave, -1+11 =10 but also +3+7

Comment: *my current dynamic programming approach solution...* I don't see the code for that. I see only the set and two pointer ones. Please add the code for your dynamic programming approach.

Comment: @ymmx i have removed 3 and 7 from the arr, i am looking for an iterative solution using `dynamic programming` to solve the problem in 0(n) time complexity

Comment: @SomeDude the section example, the codes displayed there is what you are asking for

Comment: If you actually solved this with `O(log n)` time complexity, that's *better* than `O(n)` time complexity. That said, you're almost certainly wrong that it's `O(log n)`; solving a problem like this can't be done in less than `O(n)` unless the input is pre-sorted (and your input is not).

Comment: @ShadowRanger sorry my solution is actually `0(n log(n))` not `0(log(n))`, i have updated the post

Comment: Why do you think your current solution requires non-negative input?

Comment: @user2357112 its just a random constraint....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a solution to get all solutions

```
target = 10  # sum of (-1,11)
arr = [-1,3,2,4,7,11]

def twoSum(arr, target):
    number_bonds = {}
    res=[]
    for index, value in enumerate(arr):
        if value in number_bonds:
            res.append([arr[number_bonds[value]], arr[index]])
        number_bonds[target - value] = index
    return res

print(twoSum(arr,target))
```

the idea is to compute the number that is missing by computing the difference between the current value end the target value. the difference is stack in `number_bonds`

Comment: I can't see how its different from the set example in OP's question and how it is actually dynamic programming?

Comment: @SomeDude the solution above is using memoization, even though there is no base case, we are iterating in linear time with the for loop instead of sorting the array and reducing the time complexity to `n log(n)`

The solution above result will be done in `O(n)` time complexity

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on the solution of [ymmx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4847250/ymmx) but improved:

```
def twoSum(nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
    rest_dict = {}  # Dictionary to store A values.
    
    for index in range(len(nums)):  # Walk through in O(n) time
        value = nums[index]

        if value in rest_dict:  # Is value equal B to some previous A?
            return [index, rest_dict[value]]

        rest_dict[target - value] = index  # Store the wished B for value A
```

The idea here is: let **A** and **B** be integers such that `A + B = target`. For each number **A** in `nums`, save the **B** (rest of `target - A`) in a dictionary `{rest: index}`. Repeat the procedure but now check if the next value **A'** is in the dictionary. It means, check if `A' = B`. If true, return their indexes.